# flutter : Mixins can't be instantiated

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, rxdart

i'm using flutter old version right now i'm update latest version. in old version in this core was runing fine but when i was updated the latest version this is not working showing, Mixins can't be instantiated. dart(mixins instantiate) [14,30] flutter error. please help me how to fix this issue.

source code :

error line screen short : https://prnt.sc/12yc5h9

sidebarlayout.dart

```
class SideBarLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
        create: (context) => NavigationBloc(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, NavigationStates>(
              builder: (context, navigationState) {
                return navigationState as Widget;
              },
            ),
            SideBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

navigation.dart

```
enum NavigationEvents {
  HomePageClickedEvent,
  MyAccountClickedEvent,
  MyOrdersClickedEvent,
  SignUpClickedEvent,
  SignInClickedEvent,
}

abstract class NavigationStates {}

mixin NavigationBloc implements Bloc<NavigationEvents, NavigationStates> {
  @override
  NavigationStates get initialState => MyAccountsPage();

  @override
  Stream<NavigationStates> mapEventToState(NavigationEvents event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case NavigationEvents.HomePageClickedEvent:
        yield HomePage();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.MyAccountClickedEvent:
        yield MyAccountsPage();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.MyOrdersClickedEvent:
        yield MyOrdersPage();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.SignUpClickedEvent:
        yield SignupPage();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.SignInClickedEvent:
        yield SigninPage();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

hope i will get answer zone, thank you guys.

Comment: Why is `NavigationBloc` a mixin if you are using it as a normal class with: `(context) => NavigationBloc()`?

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
mixin NavigationBloc implements Bloc<NavigationEvents, NavigationStates> {
```

Replace **mixin** with **class**